# error when executing php artisan migrate seed in console

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I write `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` in the console of the root folder of a project, when I run this command, it takes near to 1 minute then it returns \

*In PackageServiceProvider.php line 14:*

> syntax error, unexpected 'Package' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

**PackageServiceProvider.php:**

```
namespace Spatie\LaravelPackageTools;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use ReflectionClass;
use Spatie\LaravelPackageTools\Exceptions\InvalidPackage;

abstract class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected Package $package; /*  line 14 */

    abstract public function configurePackage(Package $package): void;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registeringPackage();

        $this->package = new Package();

        $this->package->setBasePath($this->getPackageBaseDir());

        $this->configurePackage($this->package);

        if (empty($this->package->name)) {
            throw InvalidPackage::nameIsRequired();
        }

        foreach($this->package->configFileNames as $configFileName) {
            $this->mergeConfigFrom($this->package->basePath("/../config/{$configFileName}.php"), $configFileName);
        }

        $this->packageRegistered();

        return $this;
    }
.
.
.
.
}
```

the project's author's PHP version: 7.4.19 
my PHP version: 7.3.27 
I'm noob in laravel, so if I have to show up with more info about the issue tell me. \

#### ***edit***

after updating the PHP version to *7.4.21* 
I wrote the command and it returned

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Business-Manager>php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > y


   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\Business-Manager\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\Business-Manager\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:18
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\Business-Manager\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:43
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::new(Object(PDOException))
```

my MySQL accounts :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2M5H.png)

Comment: Update your php version to 7.4+

Comment: @OMIShah can you check the question again please

Comment: It's MySQL username and password access problem. You have provided wrong MySQL username or password

Comment: its 100% true, in .env file also the same

Comment: Lmao, you have set forge as username in the .environment file but you have an user with the username root in your MySQL table !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`protected Package $package;`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-package-tools/blob/master/src/PackageServiceProvider.php#L14) is PHP `7.4`, it should be like `protected $package;`.

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-package-tools/blob/8655759ee47b95fdf45a94955c9b5f686e6a12b3/composer.json#L18), it required `php ^7.4` or `^8.0`, so you have to change your PHP to either of those.

[This is another](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-package-tools) place to see the composer package you are downloading, to see more info about it...

Comment: I upgrade the version and write the command again, I update the question you can see what is the new issue

Comment: Your DB username and password in `.env` are not correct

Answer (score -1):

import suitable class in the top.

```
use Facade\Ignition\Support\Packagist\Package;
```